# How to create a rotating thumbnails functionality in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need the thumbnails to rotate every time the user hovers over an image. Here is my failed attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

       $('img').hover(function() {

            theImage = $(this).attr('id');
            otherImages = $(this).attr('class').split('@');
            rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage);

       }, function() {
           //
       });

    });

    function rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage) {

        for (i=0; i < otherImages.length; i++) {
            setInterval($('#'+theImage).attr('src', otherImages[i]), 1000);
        }

    }
</script>

<img id="myImage" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" class="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png@http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/yahoo_logo_us_061509.png@http://dogandcat.com/images/cat2.jpg" width="174" height="130"  />
```

Does anyone know how this may be accomplished?

Comment: Surely they can't be a shortage of jQuery image/thumbnail rotation libraries on the internet which can be used as examples?

Comment: That's not how `setInterval` is supposed to be called.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Swap to the next image each time the image is hovered?  Or, while the image is hovered, show each image for one second and then move to the next one?

Comment: @pst reason why I can't use any of those rotating gallery plugins is because the images in need of rotating needs to be served in the specific way I gave in my example. As url paths in the class attribute.

Comment: I'm not suggesting *using* any of them, just seeing how this sort of task has been accomplished :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some issues here.

1. `setInterval` requires a function reference as it's first argument, but you are executing code that returns a jQuery object.
2. `setInterval` executes the first function repeatedly at the specified interval.  Is that what you are trying to do?  Swap images every second?
3. Depending on how you correct the first issue, you could run into an issue where `i` is `otherImages.length` and thus the `src` is set to `undefined`.
4. Assuming you worked around issue 3, you will have the problem that the image swaps will happen imperceptibly fast and it will appear as though the last image is always displayed.

Instead, don't use a loop.  Increment a counter each time a new image is displayed.  Try this:

```
function rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage) {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('#'+theImage).attr('src', otherImages[i++]);
        if (i >= otherImages.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: This works great! Only issue is after all the images have rotated it stops. Is there a way to have to continue again from the start even after the entire set of images have finished rotating?

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a [fully-functional example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/vfpK4/4/). This addresses some of the issues that @gilly3 notes, but uses closures instead of an incrementing counter to keep track of the current image:

```
$(function() {

    $('img').hover(function() {
        // declaring these variables here will preserve
        // the references in the function called by setInterval
        var $img = $(this),
           imageList = $img.attr('class').split('@'),
           intervalId;
        // start the cycle
        intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
            var next = imageList.pop();
            if (next) {
                $img.attr('src', next);
            } else {
                // stop the cycle
                intervalId = window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, function() {});

});
```

As you can see, using a closure is much easier when you declare the function passed to `setInterval` inline, rather than as a separate, named function. You could still have a `rotateThumbs` function if you wanted, but you might need to do some more work to ensure that the variables were being passed properly.

**Edit**: I made an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/vfpK4/6/) that continues to cycle as long as the mouse is hovering.

Comment: I don't think that Sam wants to stop at the end of the cycle.

Comment: @natedavisolds - I think you're right. I added an updated version to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted the answer for Sam, taking pre-loading the image into account, so that you won't have a possible deplay at the first rotation.

```
function rotateThumbs(otherImages, theImage) {
        if(!$('#'+theImage).data('setup')){
            $('#'+theImage).data('setup', true); // do not double pre-loading images
            var $body = $('body');
            for(var j = 0; j < otherImages.length; j++){
                $body.append($('<img/>').attr('src', otherImages[j])
                .css('display', 'none'));
            }
        }
        var i= 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#'+theImage).attr('src', otherImages[i++]);
            if(i >= otherImages.length){i = 0}
        }, 1000);
}
```